# Updating plugins from the admin doesn't work

Tags: craft3

Suddenly getting this strange error every time I try to update Craft or any plugins through the admin;

```
Status: Internal Server Error

Response: <pre>PHP Fatal Error &#039;yii\base\ErrorException&#039; with message &#039;Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes)&#039; 

in /Users/a/Sites/askrembla/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/Solver.php:220

Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\ErrorHandler-&gt;handleFatalError()
#1 {main}</pre>
```

Memory and all that is fine as far as I can tell, so not sure why this error is thrown. Will continue investigating on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is definitely not fine, the error message is very explicit:

> Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

You need to raise your PHP memory limits. Craft requires a minimum of 256MB to run properly.

> https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/requirements.html

Comment: Hmm. Strange. I seem to have conflicting PHP instances. Should have been 1G.